# Cannot get OSK to display

Tags: c#, wpf, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to write a desktop application where if I click certain buttons OSK will appear. I try calling it with the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

But the following error displays each time:

"Could not start On Screen Keyboard"

Why would that happen?

**UPDATE:**

If I change the debugging mode from any CPU to 64x the issue is resolved. But I would like for the OSK to show up automatically when a text is selected in tablet mode, also why is there any way to get the tablet mode OSK to show up?

Comment: What exactly are the "certain buttons" that you wish the OSK to appear for? Usually, the OSK *should* appear when a `<TextBox />` is focused (and a touch-screen is detected). Are you defining a "tablet mode" yourself, or is the device you're using a actually tablet? Could you tell us a bit more about the scope of your app and what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

This is my experience in getting OSK started using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe").  I have only tested on Windows 7 64-bit and Windows 10 64-bit and using Visual Studio 2015.  The behavior is different on the two Windows versions.

There are three relevant build options:

1. Any CPU, Prefer 32-bit checked (default):

On Windows 7 using osk.exe works ok.

On Windows 10 none of osk.exe, \Windows\System32\osk.exe, or \windows\SysWOW64\osk.exe works (probably your situation).

2. Any CPU, Prefer 32-bit not checked:

On Windows 7 using osk.exe works ok.

On Windows 10, only \Windows\System32\osk.exe works.

3. x64:

On Windows 10, osk.exe and \Windows\System32\osk.exe work.

The platform target (Any CPU) and the checkbox for Prefer 32-bit are in Project Properties, Build tab.  The default is to have Prefer 32-bit checked (makes smaller executables).  This means the application most likely runs in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit system.  In the Task Manager you will see a *32 on Windows 7 and a (32-bit) on Windows 10.

With it unchecked, the application will run in 64-bit mode on a 64-bit system and calling \Windows\System32\osk.exe will find everything it needs.  I haven't investigated why the behavior changed in Windows 10, but the bottom line is to use Any CPU with Prefer 32-bit unchecked and specify the full path to OSK, i.e. \Windows\System32\osk.exe.

\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe will start TabTip.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered an undocumented COM interface for controlling the touch keyboard. Check the code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40921638/332528