# access on screen keyboard from windev

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard, windev

In Windows 8 and Windows 10 before Anniversary update (summer 2016) it was possible to show touch keyboard by using (french version) :

```
LanceAppliAssociée("C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip32.exe")
```

Since the anniversary update, it does not work anymore. Some people have found a workaround by simulating a clic on the tabtip icon on the systray.
I thank them for this solution. You can find the original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774139/show-touch-keyboard-tabtip-exe-in-windows-10-anniversary-edition).

This is just the translation in windev code (french version):

```
EXTERNE "KeyConst.WL"
Handle_Systray,Handle_SystrayZoneNotif,Handle_BtnTabTip sont des entiers
Handle_Systray=API("User32","FindWindowA","Shell_TrayWnd",Null) //récupère le handle systray
SI Handle_Systray<>0 ALORS 
    Handle_SystrayZoneNotif=API("User32","FindWindowExA",Handle_Systray,Null,"TrayNotifyWnd",Null) //récupère le handle de zone de notification du systray
    SI Handle_SystrayZoneNotif<>0 ALORS 
        Handle_BtnTabTip = API("User32","FindWindowExA",Handle_SystrayZoneNotif,Null,"TIPBand",Null) //récupère le handle du bouton du clavier virtuel
        API("User32","PostMessageA",Handle_BtnTabTip,WM_LBUTTONDOWN,0,0) //simule le clic
        API("User32","PostMessageA",Handle_BtnTabTip,WM_LBUTTONUP,0,0)
    FIN
FIN
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
LanceAppliAssociée("osk.exe")
```