# TabTip.exe Toggle in Windows 7 (C#)

Tags: c#, toggle, user32

I found a solution for my TabTip Toggle here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774139/show-touch-keyboard-tabtip-exe-in-windows-10-anniversary-edition/40921638#40921638)

It's working like a charm on W8 and W10 but it won't run on W7. I got this exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Das COM-Objekt des Typs "UIHostNoLaunch" kann nicht in den Schnittstellentyp "ITipInvocation" umgewandelt werden. Dieser Vorgang konnte nicht durchgeführt werden, da der QueryInterface-Aufruf an die COM-Komponente für die Schnittstelle mit der IID "{37C994E7-432B-4834-A2F7-DCE1F13B834B}" aufgrund des folgenden Fehlers nicht durchgeführt werden konnte: Schnittstelle nicht unterstützt (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

Unfortunately I don't understand how the code is working in the link above so it's hard for me to find a solution.

I hope someone can help me!