# Launching the touch keyboard (Tabtip.exe) from non-admin account on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, uac

I am launching the touch keyboard in an administrator account from my application on a button press as follows :

```
 var progFiles = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink";
 var keyboardPath = Path.Combine(progFiles, "TabTip.exe");
 Process.Start(keyboardPath);
```

However from a non-admin account, the touch keyboard does not launch.

I have tried various techniques (using ShellExecuteEx, CreateProcessWithLogonW, impersonation etc) with no luck.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Is it WinForms, WPF, UWP ?

Comment: I guess the problem is that you don't have access to this directory. You could however copy the software into your app data folder (bin/debug or bin/release)

Comment: @Tony : WPF, worked fine on windows 8.1 for non admin account

Comment: Have you tried int oskID = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "osk" ).Id;
 

And for close it:

 

System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById( oskID ).Kill();

Answer (score 6):

After lots of tests, I found : [Show touch keyboard (TabTip.exe) in Windows 10 Anniversary edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774139/show-touch-keyboard-tabtip-exe-in-windows-10-anniversary-edition)

So the issues is with a bug in windows 10 Anniversary edition.

From that link I used the C# code:

```
    var uiHostNoLaunch = new UIHostNoLaunch();
    var tipInvocation = (ITipInvocation)uiHostNoLaunch;
    tipInvocation.Toggle(GetDesktopWindow());
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(uiHostNoLaunch);


   [ComImport, Guid("4ce576fa-83dc-4F88-951c-9d0782b4e376")]
   class UIHostNoLaunch
   {
   }

   [ComImport, Guid("37c994e7-432b-4834-a2f7-dce1f13b834b")]
   [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
   interface ITipInvocation
   {
       void Toggle(IntPtr hwnd);
   }

   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
   static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
```

Answer (score -1):

"JD." said the answer to his question was "ITipInvocation.Toggle()".
However, there are times in which this is *not* true.

In Win10 Ver 1803, DesktopMode, there is no reliable way to
toggle the "Touch Keyboard" on|off [ ITipInvocation.Toggle() ];
nor can you *reliably* discover if it's "up" ( on screen )
[ IFrameworkInputPane.Location() ]; both routines fail *randomly*.

Instead, ensure that "TabTIP.EXE" and "....InputApp.EXE"
only run when the keyboard is "up" ( on screen ); see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51376030/5732431

Comment: For future reference, just edit your original post. If there's any issues with undeleting it, raise a custom mod flag.

Comment: Now that I understand the extent to which robots operate here,  I shouldn't have any (major) problems in the future, @Yvette.