# How to enforce Microsoft tablet to show Numeric Keyboard only when a textbox is focused?

Tags: c#

It's 2022 and yet i haven't been able to find an answer for C# Click once application where i can force the touch screen keyboard to be numeric only by changing the properties of the textbox. And please don't tell me us WPF Controls.
If there is no answer please tell me so i can send this question to the CEO of Microsoft.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using WinForms?

Comment: Yes, i love WinForms

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "TabTip.exe"? (C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip.exe)
[Show touch keyboard (TabTip.exe) in Windows 10 Anniversary edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774139/show-touch-keyboard-tabtip-exe-in-windows-10-anniversary-edition)

Comment: I did, horrible. It's not suppose to be that complicated. Android had that feature in 2010. All you have to do is change properties. I just want confirmation that there is no answer, so i can escalate this problem to Microsoft. I know, they'll fix it.